# d_name comparison with a cstring generating core dump

Tags: c++11, coredump, dirent.h

I am using dirent.h in c++ in order to get the available directories and files in my directory, the issue that it is listing in addition to the available directories and files a "." and ".."
To remove them I added an if statement before the print.
The code is as follows:

```
if ((dir = opendir (".")) != NULL) {

    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) 
    {

        if( !strcmp( ent->d_name, "." )){
            printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
        }   

        closedir (dir);
    }
}
else {
  //could not open directory 
  printf("Error opening directory");
}
```

it is not giving me a compilation error but when executing it is giving me 
"double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000016d3010 ***
Aborted (core dumped)"
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!strcmp` comparison is a bug but it has nothing to do with the crash. That's
caused by closing the directory and then trying to continue reading entries from it.

In the following program your errors are commented out and corrected.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DIR * dir = NULL;
    if ((dir = opendir (".")) != NULL) {

        struct dirent * ent = NULL;
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) 
        {

            // if( !strcmp( ent->d_name, "." )){ <-- Bug you have yet to find.
            if( strcmp( ent->d_name, "." )){
                printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
            }

            // closedir (dir); <-- The cause of your crash

        }
        closedir (dir);
    }
    else {
      //could not open directory 
      printf("Error opening directory");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

BTW, the language this progam is written in is C, not C++.